# How to use System.in.readLine() in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I wrote a groovy script like this:

```
print "Please enter your name:"
def name=System.in.readLine()
println "My name is : ${name}"
```

But when I ran it ,I got an exception:

> Exception thrown
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.BufferedInputStream.readLine() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: readLines(), readLines(java.lang.String), eachLine(groovy.lang.Closure), eachLine(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), eachLine(int, groovy.lang.Closure), eachLine(java.lang.String, int, groovy.lang.Closure)

And I found System.in.readLines() did work, but that method read multiple lines.
Besides, the basic input function can only work in command line. In GroovyConsole,when I run the script, I can't input anything.
Any veteran can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: notice the proposed solution "System.console().readLine()" no longer works, for another solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348142/console-readline-throws-nullpointer-exception-in-groovy

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.console().readLine()`

```
def name=System.console().readLine("Please enter your name: ")
println "My name is : ${name}"
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you a lot! But I'm still curious. Why doesn't System.in.readLine() work? The instruction book did it that way